# Lua sort table value ascending

Tags: sorting, lua, midi

I have a table I need to sort sel_notes[i].Pitch to ascending order.
These are the selected midi notes in a midi editor.

sel notes table :

```lua
sel_notes = {}
sel_notes[pitch] = {Pitch = pitch, Idx = i}
sel_notes[i] = {Pitch = pitch, Idx = i}
```

sel_notes table gives this using [table.save-1.0.lua](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SaveTableToFile):

```lua
return {
-- Table: {1}
   {
      [64]={2},
      [65]={3},
      [66]={4},
      [67]={5},
      [52]={6},
      [69]={7},
      [68]={8},
      [55]={9},
      [56]={10},
      [57]={11},
      [58]={12},
      [59]={13},
      [60]={14},
      [61]={15},
      [62]={16},
      [63]={17},
   },
-- Table: {2}
   {
      ["Pitch"]=63,
      ["Idx"]=64,
   },
-- Table: {3}
   {
      ["Pitch"]=52,
      ["Idx"]=65,
   },
-- Table: {4}
   {
      ["Pitch"]=58,
      ["Idx"]=66,
   },
-- Table: {5}
   {
      ["Pitch"]=52,
      ["Idx"]=67,
   },
-- Table: {6}
   {
      ["Pitch"]=52,
      ["Idx"]=67,
   },
-- Table: {7}
   {
      ["Pitch"]=58,
      ["Idx"]=69,
   },
-- Table: {8}
   {
      ["Pitch"]=63,
      ["Idx"]=68,
   },
-- Table: {9}
   {
      ["Pitch"]=52,
      ["Idx"]=55,
   },
-- Table: {10}
   {
      ["Pitch"]=58,
      ["Idx"]=56,
   },
-- Table: {11}
   {
      ["Pitch"]=63,
      ["Idx"]=57,
   },
-- Table: {12}
   {
      ["Pitch"]=58,
      ["Idx"]=69,
   },
-- Table: {13}
   {
      ["Pitch"]=63,
      ["Idx"]=59,
   },
-- Table: {14}
   {
      ["Pitch"]=52,
      ["Idx"]=60,
   },
-- Table: {15}
   {
      ["Pitch"]=52,
      ["Idx"]=61,
   },
-- Table: {16}
   {
      ["Pitch"]=63,
      ["Idx"]=62,
   },
-- Table: {17}
   {
      ["Pitch"]=63,
      ["Idx"]=68,
   },
}
```

[image: Midi Editor Notes]

I need the table sorted so if I do this

```lua
for 1 = 1, 15 do
  note = sel_notes[i].Pitch
  index = sel_notes[i].Idx
  print(note,index)
end
```

I will get this:

```
52 55
52 60
52 61
52 65
52 67
58 56
58 58
58 63
58 66
58 69
63 57
63 59
63 62
63 64
63 68
```

So then I'll be able to change the pitch value of the notes so they match the pitch value of another table that has the chord notes.
So: 
pitch 52 to 55
pitch 58 to 59
pitch 63 to 62

Comment: Use `table.sort(sel_notes,  function (a,b) return a.Pitch .. a.Idx < b.Pitch .. b.Idx end )` and maybe check for nil.

Comment: Nice story, but what's your question? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`table.sort`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.sort) method.

The first argument is a table and the second (optional) is a function that returns whether its first argument is smaller than the second.

Of course there's the problem of the rather weird table structure, so you need to get rid of the first element, which is meaningless. The easiest way for doing this would be using [`table.remove`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.remove).

So something like

```lua
local function sort(tab)
   table.remove(tab, 1) -- Remove first element
   table.sort(tab, function(a, b)
      return true -- Your sorting criterion goes here
   end)
end
```